# Modal dialog reactivity in meteor

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm having a problem getting a checkbox selection to re-render a modal dialog when its checked.

I'm trying to display (or enable, I've tried both) some input fields depending on some check boxes being selected.

The HTML code is as follows (both disable and totally removed options)

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="joinTradeCat" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Trade Category</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="joinTradeCat" placeholder = "Required" {{#unless joinTradie}} disabled="disabled" {{/unless}}>
      </div>   {{#if joinStudent}}
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="joinCourse" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Course</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="joinCourse" placeholder = "Required">
      </div>
    </div>
    {{/if}}
</div>
```

The template functions are as follows

```
Template.joinLayoutInner.events({
  'click #joinTradieCheck': function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    console.log("checkbox clicked");
    var checked = joinTradieCheck.checked?true:false;
    Session.set("joinTradieTag", checked);
  } 
});   

Template.joinLayoutInner.helper({
  joinTradie: function() {
    return Session.get("joinTradieTag");
  } 
});
```

When I toggle the joinTradieCheck check box, the session variable changes happily, but the layout doesn't change (either enables the edit, or displays the one in the #if).

Am I going about this the right way? Is it because I'm in a modal-boy div?

Comment: Did you forget to post the `joinStudent` helper or a you missing it? Also shouldn't it just be `disabled` instead of `disabled="disabled"` for disabling the input?

Comment: I didn't add the joinStudent helper, its the same as the joinTradie one. HTML could be simplified, but that's not the issue, the lack of reactivity is.

Comment: In that case I would say your code is correct, being in a modal-body div cannot be the problem. Still an SSCCE would be nice and probably help you in debugging this. I would first check whether the `joinTradie` or `joinStudent` helpers ever get executed. If not try to add the helpers directly to the template (not in the helpers dictionary). Now that I am saying this, could it be a simple typo: you are missing an `s`, `Template.joinLayoutInner.helper` should be `Template.joinLayoutInner.helpers`?

Comment: SSCCE? But, your spot on Toboid. Missed the 's'.  Thankyou

Comment: Glad I could help, I'll add this as an answer so the question is solved. SSCCE = Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example (http://sscce.org/). I was asking for an SSCCE because the code you posted was incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very small typo, a missing `s`.

```
Template.joinLayoutInner.helper
```

should be

```
Template.joinLayoutInner.helpers
```

Documentation can be found here: http://docs.meteor.com/#template_helpers